# $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R ,x \lt y \implies \exists z,$s.t. $x \lt z \lt y$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am going through Apostol's and wondering if I am answering this questions correctly. It is as follows.

If $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary real numbers with $x \lt y$, prove that there is at least one real $z$ satisfying $x \lt z \lt y$.

Here is my answer

> Choose $n$ such that $n \gt \displaystyle \frac 1 {y-x}$. Let $\displaystyle z=x+ \frac {1}{n}$ then $y>z>x$

Comment: Well, you need to prove that such an $n$ exists. And that your $z$ actually satisfies the inequalities you claim. This is far from the easiest way of doing this question though.

Comment: This is one of those cases where drawing a picture will tell you how to do this in as easy a way as @Chris hints.

Comment: There is a more direct approach. Your proof works, but you have to show that there is such an $n$. On the other hand, there is a simple formula for one $z$ between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is there any easy way to show that such an n exists?

Comment: If not, what would be a hint towards a simpler method?

Comment: Because you chose the letter $n$, I assumed you wanted $n$ to be an integer, but it is clear you don't need $n$ to be an integer.

Comment: It can be any real number.

Comment: Then it is easy to prove that there is such an $n$. What is a number bigger than $\frac{1}{y-x}$?

Comment: To spell out Lubin's hint just a tad more:  Suppose you have a number line, and you put dots where the values $x$ and $y$ are (with $x < y$).  Why is it that there will always be points between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @JavaMan The way I reasoned it is that there would always be some n such that $y-x> \frac 1n$. So $n> \frac 1 {y-x}$ So, geometrically $x+ \frac 1n$ would be $z=x+ \frac 1n$ so x<y<z like I originally posted. But can't we just assume that n exists?

Comment: Existence is by the archimedian principle which I think you can show using supremum and the completeness axiom

Comment: Thanks Ben. That's the way it should probably be done.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the average of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: -1 If the OP is seeking for hints in the comments, please do not provide a solution.  Now, the OP doesn't have to _think_.

Comment: Sometimes the obvious needs to be pointed out.  And the OP still needs to understand how to prove the answer is correct.

Comment: This not one of those times.

Comment: This is absolutely one of those times.