# If $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary real numbers with $x < y$, prove that there exists at least one real satisfying $x < z < y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

This is a question from Apostol Calculus section I.3.12 q1

> If $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary real numbers with $x < y$, prove that there exists at least one real satisfying $x < z < y$

I've seen a lot of answers such as this one [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318251/forall-x-y-in-mathbb-r-x-lt-y-implies-exists-z-s-t-x-lt-z-lt-y) that use the archimedean property of real numbers. tl;dr let $z = \frac{y+x}{2}$

**My question is the following:** I attempted solving this using a different approach, relying on Theorems I.32 and 34. **I'm wondering if the approach is valid, specifically the strategy.** (I'm sure there are issues with the details, I'm new to proofs and working on smoothing out the details).

> **Theorem I.30** "Archimedean Property" If $x > 0$ and if $y$ is an arbitrary real number, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$.
>
> **Theorem I.32:** Let $h$ be a given positive integer and let $S$ be a set of real numbers.
>
> (a) *If $S$ has a supremum, then for some $x$ in $S$ we have*$$x > \sup S - h$$
>
> (b) *If S has an infimum, then for some $x \text{ in } S$ we have* $$x < \inf S + h$$
>
> **Theorem I.34:** Given two nonempty subsets $S$ and $T$ of $\mathbb R$, such that $$s \leq t$$ for every $s \in S \text{ and every } t \in T$. Then $S$ has a supremum, and $T$ has an infimum, and they satisfy the inequality $$\sup S \leq \inf T$$

**My attempt**

Let $S \text{ and } T$ be nonempty sets of real numbers such that $x < y$ for all $x \in S$ and all $y \in T$.

Then, arbitrary $y$ in $T$ is an upper bound for $S$, so $S$ has $\sup S$ such that $$\sup S \geq x \text{ for all } x \in S \quad \text{ (1) }$$ Moreover, from the definition of supremum, we have $$x \leq \sup S \lt y \quad \text{ (2) }$$

Same reasoning for $T$. Arbitrary $x$ in $S$ is a lower bound for $T$, so $T$ has $\inf T$ such that $$\inf T \leq y \text{ for all } y \in T \quad \text{ (3) }$$ Again from the definition of infimum we have, $$x \lt \inf T \leq y \quad \text{ (4) }$$

Assume there exists a $z$ such that $x < z$ for all $x \in S$ and $z < y$. for all $y \in T$. Then $z$ is an upper bound of $S$ so $$\sup S < z \quad \text{ (5) }$$ and, by definition of supremum, we have $$x \leq \sup S \lt z \quad \text{ (6) }$$

Additionally, $z$ is a lower bound of $T$ so $$\inf T > z \quad \text{ (7) }$$ and, by definition of infimum, we have $$z \lt \inf T \leq y \quad \text{ (8) }$$

From (8) and (7) we have $$x \leq \sup S \lt z \lt \inf T \leq y$$ which becomes $$x < z < y$$

Comment: Did you really mean $x<y<z$ in the title?

Comment: Do you want to obtain $x<z<y$ as in your last line (in which case take $z=(x+y)/2$), or $x<y<z$ (in which case take $z=2y-x$) as in your title (and a problem duplication underneath it)?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos apologies, fixed the title. I understand that the approach of taking $z = \frac{x +y}{2}$, my question is about if you can solve this not using that theorem. I'll fix the intro paragraph to make that more clear

Comment: @JakeKirsch The statement duplication still contains the typo.

Comment: @J.G. thanks, fixed that part as well

Comment: Your proof is basically "let's suppose $z$ has the needed properties . Then $z$ has the needed properties" with lots of stuff in between.

Comment: Also it is hard to understand what are the fixed $x$ and $y$ and what are the non fixed ones.

Comment: @Junkyards shoot I think I see that now At a high level I'm basically saying "if there is $x<y$, assume there is $x < z$ and $z < y$, then $x < z < y$?

Comment: That is kinda what you did. Also, your second theorem is kind of another way of defining supremums and infimums, and your third theorem does not give a strict inequality. Even though, you can use your first theorem to prove the result, by instead proving that between 0 and a strictly positive real number there's always another real number.

Comment: Agreed. Just a note, these theorems are verbatim from Apostol, and I agree that Theorem I.32 is a restatement of the definitions, in fact, that is what Apostol uses to prove Theorem I.32.